# How to prevent GNU ld from reordering the object files?

Tags: assembly, linker, gnu

I have a function implemented in i386 assembly spreading over multiple `.s` files. The result of the function depends on the order the machine code is concatenated, for example:

```
$ gcc -m32 -Wl,-N -W -Wall -Werror -s -O2 -o calladd calladd.c add10.s double.s add1.s ret.s && ./calladd a b; echo $?
27
$ gcc -m32 -Wl,-N -W -Wall -Werror -s -O2 -o calladd calladd.c add10.s add1.s double.s ret.s && ./calladd a b; echo $?
28
```

I always want to have the code in `ret.s` last (because it contains the `ret` instruction), and I want to vary the order of the other `.s` files.

How can I make sure that GNU ld emits the code `.s` files in the order I've specified them? It seems to work by default, but I want the solution to be more resilient, i.e. explicitly disable reordering for these `.s` files even if reordering gets enabled for other files. Which command-line flags are relevant?

Preferably I want to do it without a linker script.

My example files are:

```
# calladd.c:
extern int add10(int) __attribute__((regparm(1)));
int main(int argc, char **argv) { (void)argv; return add10(argc); }

# add10.s:
.text
.globl add10
add10:
addl $10, %eax

# add1.s:
.text
.globl add1
add1:
addl $1, %eax

# double.s:
.text
.globl double
double:
addl %eax, %eax

# ret.s:
.text
ret
```

Comment: I don't think this can be done. I recommend you to use the C preprocessor to concatenate the files before assembling

Comment: @fuz: Thank you for your comment. In my real-life situation it's not possible to manipulate `.s` files, because the moment I need to reorder code I have the `.o` files only.

Comment: You could use `ld -r` to amalgamate the object files and hope that that works as you expect.

Comment: By default, unless you override the behaviour in a linker script, the GNU linker puts things in each in section in the order it encounters them. Padding is potential problem however, as the linker should  align the start of each object file's  `.text` section according to the alignment it requires. A better way to concatenate these files would be concatenate the source files into one source file. Either with `cat`, `.include`, or `#include`.

Comment: @RossRidge: Thank you for the insights. I use `gcc -Wl,-N` to avoid problems with padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment of @RossRidge: GNU ld doesn't reorder source files by default, just rely on that. To avoid extra bytes inserted because of alignment, don't use `.align` or anything similar in the `.s` files, and put them to the same section `.text`.